# in python compilation EOFError SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, encryption

I have code and while i run it

```
import sys

MSGS = ["315c4eeaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b8fa00dc71d885a804e5ee9fa40b16349c146fb778cdf2d3aff021dfff5b403b510d0d0455468aeb98622b137dae857553ccd8883a7bc37520e06e515d22c954eba5025b8cc57ee59418ce7dc6bc41556bdb36bbca3e8774301fbcaa3b83b220809560987815f65286764703de0f3d524400a19b159610b11ef3e",
"234c02ecbbfbafa3ed18510abd11fa724fcda2018a1a8342cf064bbde548b12b07df44ba7191d9606ef4081ffde5ad46a5069d9f7f543bedb9c861bf29c7e205132eda9382b0bc2c5c4b45f919cf3a9f1cb74151f6d551f4480c82b2cb24cc5b028aa76eb7b4ab24171ab3cdadb8356f",
"32510ba9a7b2bba9b8005d43a304b5714cc0bb0c8a34884dd91304b8ad40b62b07df44ba6e9d8a2368e51d04e0e7b207b70b9b8261112bacb6c866a232dfe257527dc29398f5f3251a0d47e503c66e935de81230b59b7afb5f41afa8d661cb",
"32510ba9aab2a8a4fd06414fb517b5605cc0aa0dc91a8908c2064ba8ad5ea06a029056f47a8ad3306ef5021eafe1ac01a81197847a5c68a1b78769a37bc8f4575432c198ccb4ef63590256e305cd3a9544ee4160ead45aef520489e7da7d835402bca670bda8eb775200b8dabbba246b130f040d8ec6447e2c767f3d30ed81ea2e4c1404e1315a1010e7229be6636aaa",
"3f561ba9adb4b6ebec54424ba317b564418fac0dd35f8c08d31a1fe9e24fe56808c213f17c81d9607cee021dafe1e001b21ade877a5e68bea88d61b93ac5ee0d562e8e9582f5ef375f0a4ae20ed86e935de81230b59b73fb4302cd95d770c65b40aaa065f2a5e33a5a0bb5dcaba43722130f042f8ec85b7c2070",
"32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd2061bbde24eb76a19d84aba34d8de287be84d07e7e9a30ee714979c7e1123a8bd9822a33ecaf512472e8e8f8db3f9635c1949e640c621854eba0d79eccf52ff111284b4cc61d11902aebc66f2b2e436434eacc0aba938220b084800c2ca4e693522643573b2c4ce35050b0cf774201f0fe52ac9f26d71b6cf61a711cc229f77ace7aa88a2f19983122b11be87a59c355d25f8e4",
"32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd90f1fa6ea5ba47b01c909ba7696cf606ef40c04afe1ac0aa8148dd066592ded9f8774b529c7ea125d298e8883f5e9305f4b44f915cb2bd05af51373fd9b4af511039fa2d96f83414aaaf261bda2e97b170fb5cce2a53e675c154c0d9681596934777e2275b381ce2e40582afe67650b13e72287ff2270abcf73bb028932836fbdecfecee0a3b894473c1bbeb6b4913a536ce4f9b13f1efff71ea313c8661dd9a4ce",
"315c4eeaa8b5f8bffd11155ea506b56041c6a00c8a08854dd21a4bbde54ce56801d943ba708b8a3574f40c00fff9e00fa1439fd0654327a3bfc860b92f89ee04132ecb9298f5fd2d5e4b45e40ecc3b9d59e9417df7c95bba410e9aa2ca24c5474da2f276baa3ac325918b2daada43d6712150441c2e04f6565517f317da9d3",
"271946f9bbb2aeadec111841a81abc300ecaa01bd8069d5cc91005e9fe4aad6e04d513e96d99de2569bc5e50eeeca709b50a8a987f4264edb6896fb537d0a716132ddc938fb0f836480e06ed0fcd6e9759f40462f9cf57f4564186a2c1778f1543efa270bda5e933421cbe88a4a52222190f471e9bd15f652b653b7071aec59a2705081ffe72651d08f822c9ed6d76e48b63ab15d0208573a7eef027",
"466d06ece998b7a2fb1d464fed2ced7641ddaa3cc31c9941cf110abbf409ed39598005b3399ccfafb61d0315fca0a314be138a9f32503bedac8067f03adbf3575c3b8edc9ba7f537530541ab0f9f3cd04ff50d66f1d559ba520e89a2cb2a83"]
TARGET = "32510ba9babebbbefd001547a810e67149caee11d945cd7fc81a05e9f85aac650e9052ba6a8cd8257bf14d13e6f0a803b54fde9e77472dbff89d71b57bddef121336cb85ccb8f3315f4b52e301d16e9f52f904"
INITKEY = "66396e89c9dbd8cc9874352acd6395102eafce78aa7fed28a07f6bc98d29c50b69b0339a19f8aa401a9c6d708f80c066c763fef0123148cdd8e802d05ba98777335daefcecd59c433a6b268b60bf4ef03c9a611098bb3e9a3161edc7b804a33522cfd202d2c68c57376edba8c2ca50027c61246ce2a12b0c4502175010c0a1ba4625786d911100797d8a47e98b0200c4ab000000a900000000008a0082d10000320000000000000000050000911f3edfd73e8333e8463df984ee"

msgs = [x.decode('hex') for x in MSGS]
target = TARGET.decode('hex')

key = list(INITKEY.decode('hex'))

def charxor(a,b):
    return chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b))

def strxor(a, b):     # xor two strings of different lengths
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])

def encrypt(key, msg):
    c = strxor(key, msg)
    print
    print c.encode('hex')
    return c

def isSpace(s,i):
    for x in msgs:
        if x != s and i < len(x):
            c = charxor(x[i],s[i])
            if not c.isalpha():
                return False
    return True

def printProgress():
    for i in range(len(msgs)):
        print str(i) + ": " + "".join(strxor(msgs[i],key))
        print
    print "* : " + "".join(strxor(target,key))

def main():
    '''
    -- initialize the key
    for i in range(max(map(len,msgs))):
        foundSpace = False
        for x in msgs:
            if i < len(x) and isSpace(x,i):
                key.append(charxor(x[i],' '))
                foundSpace = True
                break
        if not foundSpace:
            key.append(chr(0))
    '''

    while True:
        printProgress()
        s = int(raw_input("stridx: "))
        if s == -1:
            break
        s = msgs[s]
        for i in range(len(s)):
            c = charxor(s[i],key[i])
            print str(i) + "\t\t" + (str(c) if c.isalnum() else ' ')
        i = int(raw_input("idx: "))
        c = raw_input("char: ")[0]
        key[i] = charxor(s[i],c)

    print "".join(key).encode('hex')

main()
```

i should get decrypted words here they are:
0: We can factor the number 15 with quantum computers. We can also factor the number 15 with a dog trained to bark three times - Robert Harley

1: Euler would probably enjoy that now his theorem becomes a corner stone of crypto - Annonymous on Euler's theorem

...

```
stridx: Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 79, in <module>
    main()
  Line 66, in main
    s = int(raw_input("stridx: "))
EOFErro
```

Comment: use your editor to see any invisible control characters and/or make sure all tabs are consistent (i.e not both spaces and tabs), it seems this is the issue

Comment: @Nikos M.please can you understand I am newbie in python

Comment: Why did you commented `for loop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crypto is irrelevant here.

Your `import sys` statement was mis-indented; I fixed that.

You seem to run your Python code without giving it any chance to read the standard console input. One way to do it could be to click the .py file in the Windows Explorer.

The problem, as the stack trace helpfully shows, is here:

```
s = int(raw_input("stridx: "))
```

This call waits for a string to be sent to standard input (e.g. due to a user pressing keys) which is then converted into an integer. You seem to run your program in a way when standard input is not accessible, so you get an `EOFError` (end-of-file can happen on presumably interactive input, too!).

I ran your code on Linux in a terminal; it seemed to work fine.